# unicode private area in UILabel

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, unicode, uilabel

I am trying to set up \f010 in my UILabel as unicode, but it doesn't work. This format is of Unicode Private Use Area. How do I do this? Here's how I am setting it:

```
 [homeFeedButton setTitle:@"\f010" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Comment: How do you expect the code to set up “\f010”?

Comment: sorry.. I edited the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try `NSString *str=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%C",unicodestring]; 
     // unicodestring vontains your unicode string`

Then setv as title